# Why does National Rail suggest an Off-Peak Return for a Friday morning into London? Is the ticket valid?

Tags: uk, trains

Why does National Rail suggest an Off-Peak Return for a departure from Reading to London on a Friday morning?  Clicking through to the [relevant restrictions](http://www.nationalrail.co.uk/ticket_types/restrictions/5B) clearly states that the ticket is *Not valid on trains timed to depart after 04:29 and before 09:30.*  Christmas lifting of restrictions do not start until the 23rd of December.

[image: Screenshot National Rail]

Is there a bug in the National Rail travel planner?  Is there another obscure rule that I'm not aware of?  Is the Off-Peak ticket offered valid on this service?  It *does* apply the "Railcard not valid" rule (I searched for 2 people with 1 Two Together Railcard).

[Direct link to national rail query](http://ojp.nationalrail.co.uk/service/timesandfares/RDG/STP/221217/0700/dep/070118/1400/dep).

Comment: The train in question appears to leave Worcester Shrub Hill (its origin station) at 05:11, which I thought might be the issue, but that's also after 04:29.

Comment: There's definitely something weird going on there - when I click on the link I get "Return from £33.40" and "2 singles from £48.20".

Comment: @djr That's just because gerrit has selected 2 tickets rather than 1.

Comment: @waiwai933 good point!

Comment: If you buy it as singles, it requires an "Anytime" ticket for the outward journey and an off-peak one for the return leg. On the other hand if I try it for this Friday until Sunday it says "No return fares available". So I'm sticking with claiming there's something weird there.

Comment: @AakashM I saw that (and mentioned it in the question), but I don't know if that means I am (erroneously) entitled to travel or if the ticket is invalid for the train.  It won't even let me buy an Anytime ticket with this Return if I try…

Comment: AIUI the fare is valid, as National Rail told you it is (and you bought it on that understanding, so best take the itinerary with you in case of problems). That could change for future purchases though, if it is a bug.

Comment: At a guess, either the restrictions page is right and the travel planner wrongly thinks that Fri 22nd is off peak because Christmas, or the travel planner is right and the restrictions page is wrong. But that doesn't help you very much and I have no idea how you'd resolve it.

Comment: Incidentally, if you're going to St Pancras to catch a Eurostar, you might want to look at CIV tickets ( https://www.seat61.com/UKconnections.htm#London%20International%20CIV ) which are often about the price of off peak even at peak times.

Comment: @djr I would if I knew how to purchase those.

Comment: @gerrit From a ticket counter at a station, see the link above

Comment: @djr I have booked a pair of tickets to London International CIV (without railcard as we travel during a time that it is not valid).

Answer (score 6):

Looking up the Reading to London journey on the [BR Fares](http://www.brfares.com/#home) website (not an official website, but contains details of ticketing restrictions in the national fares database), and [querying that fare](http://www.brfares.com/#faredetail?orig=0403&dest=0785&rlc=2TR&tkt=SVR), you find under the *Unpublished Restrictions* section of the Off Peak Return ticket (5B):

```
Restriction Code: 5B
OFF-PEAK

This restriction code applies on the following dates/days:
From              Until                Applies on these days:
Sun 3 Sep 2017    Sun 3 Sep 2017          Tu We Th Fr   
Mon 4 Sep 2017    Sun 17 Dec 2017      Mo Tu We Th Fr   <<<--- Should be 23rd Dec
Tues 8 May 2018   Mon 28 May 2018      Mo Tu We Th Fr   
Tues 29 May 2018  Mon 4 Jun 2018          Tu We Th Fr   
Tues 5 Jun 2018   Mon 27 Aug 2018      Mo Tu We Th Fr
```

Which to me suggests they have not correctly programmed the Christmas lifting of restrictions into the fares database - the 5B code doesn't apply after the 17th December here. If you [query that fare on the National Rail website for, say, the 15th December](http://ojp.nationalrail.co.uk/service/timesandfares/RDG/STP/151217/0700/dep/070118/1400/dep), it only offers you the Anytime Return as being valid, as expected.

Seems like a programming error in the database. Technically it should be accepted if you have been sold that ticket via the website and can produce the valid itinerary, but it might be difficult to argue this with the conductor on the day.

Comment: The 'arguing' problem probably starts at the ticket gates, which will refuse entry to an off-peak ticket at those times.

Comment: Even more than that seems to be awry -- last Tuesday I was going from Oxford to Ealing Broadway, and the National Rail planner found a departure at 17:30 with a change in Slough that it said would be OK for an Off-Peak ticket. But joining the very same GWR train at Reading at 17:57 would need an Anytime ticket -- as I found out after having jumped on an earlier (also off-peak) XC train to Reading in the hope of perhaps catching an better connection. [I boarded the GWR train there with my off-peak ticket anyway, but it was never checked].

Comment: [Some research later] Why, isn't _that_ byzantine! The off-peak single fares from either Oxford or Reading to Ealing Broadway both carry restriction code P7, which [ostensbily](http://www.nationalrail.co.uk/P7) restricts "up" (towards London) journeys only in the morning peak. However, brfares.com [shows unpublished restrictions](http://www.brfares.com/#faredetail?orig=OXF&dest=EAL&rte=700&tkt=CDS) that include several dozen 2-minute intervals in the evening where boarding at (specifically) Reading is disallowed. Where's the point in that? And why keep it secret?

Comment: [Even more thinking later] It looks like they're (clumsily) trying to code "not valid on _fast_ trains that _depart_ Paddington 1600-1915" (but valid on locals), and the "up" train I joined was simply collateral damage of that because it happened to depart Reading in the same minute as one of those fast "down"s went in the other direction. <facepalm>

Comment: AIUI the "unpublished restrictions" are intended to be a computer-readable form of the actual human-readable restrictions. Unfortunately this system of computer-readable restrictions is not able to properly represent the actual contractual restrictions on many tickets and no one seems willing or able to fix it so it can.